# Speeding up `using Distributions` in Julia

Tags: julia

On my machine, with the development version of Julia, the command `import Distributions` takes 6.6 seconds. Is there a way to make this faster? Is static precompilation going to be part of Julia 0.4?

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.4.0-dev+4603 (2015-05-02 18:25 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit 803193e* (17 days old master)
|__/                   |  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

julia> tic(); import Distributions; toc()
elapsed time: 6.62282982 seconds
6.62282982
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Static precompilation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/8745) might happen for Julia 0.4, not 100% clear yet if it'll make it in.

If you'd like to do it somewhat manually by baking it into your "system image", check out the [handy package SystemImageBuilder.jl](https://github.com/rened/SystemImageBuilder.jl).

Comment: Wow! `SystemImageBuilder.jl` is exactly what I was looking for...my program is starting in like 5 seconds now, rather than after 65 seconds. Thanks much!

Comment: I hope static compilation makes it soon; one of the barriers to using Julia is the slow start-up times.